# Display product reviews by specific attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, review

I'm trying to create the collection of latest 5 reviews from products with specific attribute (e.g. - `brand`). Here is my current code that displays just latest 5 reviews:

```
<?php 
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection();
$reviews->addStoreFilter( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
                ->addStatusFilter( Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED )
                ->setDateOrder()
                ->addRateVotes()
                ->setPageSize(5)
                        ->setCurPage(1)
                ->load();


?>
<!-- Print reviews -->
<ol>
<?php
foreach($reviews as $review) {
    $review_data = $review->getData();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $review_data['entity_pk_value'] );
    ?>
    <li>
        <h4>Review of: <?php echo $product->getName() ?></h4>
        <p><?php echo $review_data['detail']; ?></p>
    </li>
    <?php
}
?>
</ol>
```

Is there any way to apply some filter to `$reviews` collection so it'll contain just reviews from specific attribute name?

Thanks for help.

**UPD:** code that works: https://gist.github.com/dimsemenov/5845535

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume that your attribute has `int` type. In this case you can do something like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
    ->setDateOrder()
    ->addRateVotes()
    ->setPageSize(5)
    ->setCurPage(1);

$collection->getSelect()
    ->join(array('attr' => 'catalog_product_entity_int'), 'attr.entity_id = main_table.entity_pk_value', array('*'))
    ->where('attr.attribute_id = 272');
```

Where `272` is the of your attribute id.

If you also want to limit a collection to reviews of products with specific attribute set to specific value you can add something like this to the end

```
->where('attr.value = 24')
```

Where 24 is the value of your attribute.

If your attribute has different type then just replace `catalog_product_entity_int` with EAV table of your attribute.

Comment: Nevermind. Thanks for help, your solution works like a charm.